# numpy array IndexError: index is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1080

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to iterate over the pixels of an image, more specifically a screenshot i'm acquiring via ImageGrab module. Here's my code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab as ig
import numpy as np
from pynput.mouse import Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Key
from pynput import keyboard

mouse= Controller()

def onpress(key):

    try:
        pressed_key= key.char
    except AttributeError:
        pressed_key= str(key)[4:]

    if pressed_key == 'esc':
        print('Quitting process')
        return False

    elif pressed_key == 'space':
        mousepos= mouse.position
        pic= ig.grab()

        arr= np.array(pic)

        print(f'Pixel color at {mousepos}: RGB{arr[mousepos]}')
        # here the error is raised

with keyboard.Listener(on_press= onpress) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I want to inspect the RGB color of the pixel at the mouse position when the spacebar is pressed. It works fine for the "top-left-most" pixels, here are some output examples:

```
1) Pixel color at (150, 193): RGB[242 243 244]
2) Pixel color at (579, 302): RGB[0 0 0]
3) Pixel color at (887, 108): RGB[145 89 4]
```

but when I move the mouse slightly at the bottom-right of the screen (from the center just a little bit bottom-right) it raises an error like this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imagegrab.py", line 64, in <module>
    listener.join()
  File "C:\Users\marca\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 199, in join
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
  File "C:\Users\marca\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 692, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\marca\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 154, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\marca\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 237, in _process
    self.on_press(key)
  File "C:\Users\marca\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 75, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:
  File "imagegrab.py", line 42, in onpress
    print(f'{count}) Pixel color at {mousepos}: RGB{arr[mousepos]}')
IndexError: index 1152 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1080
```

---

This error IS NOT raised if I load the image using

```
pixels= pic.load()
print(f'{count}) Pixel color at {mousepos}: RGB{pixels[mousepos]}')
```

which works perfectly (here I was pointing at the top-left and bottom-right corners of the screen):

```
1) Pixel color at (0, 0): RGB(56, 36, 12)
2) Pixel color at (1914, 1016): RGB(22, 15, 5)
```

I think it has something to do with my laptop's screen DPI, as previously I had to apply a fix that was suggested [in this Github thread](https://github.com/ponty/pyscreenshot/issues/25#issuecomment-154648201), as I was having [this kind of screen-capture problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55857847/imagegrab-pyscreenshot-doesnt-capture-full-screen-if-zoom-factor-is-applied-by)

The array index shown in the error (1152), as you can see, overflows the common 1920x1080 resolution of HD screens. I have no clue in what to do to fix this, so I hope I've been clear and somebody can help me.

Comment: This is not really a numpy question. Whatever handles the screengrab is at fault. Or, no, the mouse position is off.

Comment: I agree that this isn't specifically a numpy question, but it is involved. The mouse position isn't off, it cannot be over 1080 on a 1920x1080 screen, but somehow numpy raises that error.

Comment: How is "index 1152" not off?

Comment: I mean it cannot **phisically** be over 1080 on the screen, nonetheless that's what i get

Comment: Indeed. That is why it is off.

Comment: Could it be that the coordinates are flipped ie they are x, y instead of the assumed y, x?

Comment: Yep! By flipping the acquired coordinates of the mouse (which initially were correct) now it works! Instead of ```mousepos= mouse.position``` i now define ```mousepos= (mouse.position[1], mouse.position[0])```. still, is there any better way i can achieve the same goal leaving the coordinates intact?